# MapReduce programme not producing any outputs

Tags: java, hadoop

I am currently trying to parse the hour from some twitter data. The timestamp in twitter is in epochseconds, and I am using a mapreduce programme to extract and sum the hour of the day that each tweet was posted. My java code compiles, and the hadoop job runs, however I get a blank output. After looking at the details of the hadoop job, it is telling me that merged map outputs = 0. I have tried everything and have no idea why this is not working. Even if I have not parsed the date correctly, I should still get a return of all of the tweets being recorded under `time = 23`, and this is the final else in my list of if else statements. I have put the code below:

```
public class TweetHourMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private Text hour = new Text();
    private IntWritable count = new IntWritable(1);
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] fields = value.toString().split(";");
        if (fields.length == 4) {
            String date = fields[0];
            Long aDate = Long.parseLong(date);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(aDate);
            int time = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            if (time == 0) {
                hour.set("0");
                context.write(hour, count);
                //Below this i have a list of if else statements writing out if the    time== the particular hour.
```

Comment: This check will only pass for tweets happening at noon and midnight only: `if (time == 0)`. Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: No below the last line I have a list of else if statements for all of the other hours (right through to time == 23)

Comment: Why are you filtering the hour at all? `hour.set("" + time);` is all you need.

Comment: Show your input data... How do we know `if (fields.length == 4) {` should even pass?

Comment: if (fields.length==4) flters the dataset so it only includes tweets which conform to the correct format. This does work as I have already used this statement to run a mapreduce programme to look at the length of tweets. However for some reason when I put in the code to extract the hour from the time stamp, I get a blank text file for the results (it looks like nothing is being passed to the reducer). When I remove the code relating to extracting the hour of the tweet, it runs fine.